# Overlapping test in a regex for numbers?

Tags: java, regex

I have a challenge here that is beyond my regex scope. If anyone has a suggestion it would be greatly appreciated. I haven't been able to track down anything like this and I'm not sure whether it's doable. I'm using the following expression in java:

```
"(?i)-?(([1-9]+[0-9]*)|0)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9]+)?(e-?[0-9]+)?"
```

to validate long strings (up to 255 characters) as a confirmation that they at least fit within an allowed numeric value (not necessarily for any type of calculation) and allow the option for scientific notation. The BigDecimal class wasn't doing everything I needed so there are additional checks for leading zeros and trailing zeros in the fractional part because the value must fit with the most simplified representation of the number and follow predictable protocols without any changes. All of the following are returning the results I expect:

```
String allowance = "(?i)-?(([1-9]+[0-9]*)|0)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9]+)?(e-?[0-9]+)?" ;

System.out.println("0".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert true. Confirm default
System.out.println("-42".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert true. Confirm integers only
System.out.println("0.2e543".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert true
System.out.println("1e543".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert true
System.out.println("0.2000e543".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert false : trailing zeros after fractional .2
System.out.println(".2e543".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert false : missing the leading zero
System.out.println("e543".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert false : malformed
System.out.println("0001e543".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert false : leading zeros in the integer
System.out.println("1.0".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert false : easiest match is "1"
System.out.println("0.0".matches(allowance)) ;   // assert false : easiest match is "0"
```

All of that is fine and good, but I can't figure these two out in the same expression. Maybe one or the other but not both:

```
System.out.println("-0".matches(allowance)) ;   // Supposed to be FALSE - Should just be "0"
System.out.println("0e543".matches(allowance)) ;   // Supposed to be FALSE - "0" integer rules out the exponent segment so the easiest match would be "0"
```

Is it possible to trap the segment "-?(([1-9]+[0-9]*)|0)(\.[0-9]*[1-9]+)?" as two separate but overlapping tests: 1) to rule out "-0" but only if the value doesn't have a fractional value (i.e. -0.5 would be allowable) and then jump forward to 2) rule out the next to follow "e543" exponent if the integer value comes back in the test as "0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
"(?i)(0|-?([1-9][0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])?(e-?[1-9][0-9]*)?|-?0\\.[0-9]*[1-9](e-?[1-9][0-9]*)?)"
```

Basically, you accept any of the following:

- zero without a sign, decimal, or exponent
- a non-zero number with an optional sign, decimal, or exponent
- a zero with a required decimal and an optional sign or exponent

Here's a [demonstration](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%280%7C-%3F%28%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%2a%29%28%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2a%5B1-9%5D%29%3F%28e-%3F%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%2a%29%3F%7C-%3F0%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2a%5B1-9%5D%28e-%3F%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%2a%29%3F%29%24&input=0%0A-42%0A0.2e543%0A1e543%0A0.2000e543%0A.2e543%0Ae543%0A0001e543%0A1.0%0A0.0%0A-0%0A0e543%0A5e000543).

Comment: Ah yes, I see your point. Split it into separate problem domains. Excellent. Thanks very much for the mod. It's working through all of my tests.

Comment: I caught another outlier: "5e000543" should be considered a non-allowance (leading zeros in the exponent). I added [1-9]+[0-9]* in the e-? segments and it looks like it completes it: "(?i)(0|-?([1-9]+[0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9]+)?(e-?[1-9]+[0-9]*)?|-?0\\.[0-9]*[1-9]+(e-?[1-9]+[0-9]*)?)"

Comment: @user2958405 You can simplify that a bit by tweaking some of the quantifiers--e.g. `[1-9]+[0-9]*` -> `[1-9][0-9]*`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using lookahead in the first of the pair, to not consume the ones you want to check with the second test?

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html